# Spring+Maven Property File not loading

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

I am trying to access a property file containing db configurations in a `Maven + Spring` project.

I get following error:

`Cannot load JDBC driver class '${db_driver}'`

My Property file is placed in `src/resources` folder.

Below is the tag to load property files:

```
<bean id="dbPropertyReader" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:${appenv.deployment}.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Following tag uses properties loaded:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${db_url}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db_driver}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db_username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db_password}" />
</bean>
```

Below are contents of properties file:

```
#JDBC Properties
db_driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_url=jdbc\:mysql\://hostname\:3306/xxx_dbxxx?useUnicode\=true
db_username=abcdefgh
db_password=ijklmnopq
db_removeabadoned=true
db_initialsize=1
db_maxactive=2
```

`${appenv.deployment}` is a VMArgument set as follows:

```
-Dappenv.deployment=development
```

I have checked, this value is getting populated properly.

I am getting following line in logs:

`Found key 'appenv.deployment' in [systemProperties] with type [String] and value 'development'`

Then after this I am also getting following:

`Loading properties file from class path resource [development.properties]`

But some how, the values are not getting loaded.

**Spring-Datasource.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dbPropertyReader" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:${appenv.deployment}.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${db_url}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db_driver}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db_username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db_password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${db_initialsize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${db_maxactive}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="firstConfigDataFromDB" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="tablename1" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="propertyname2" />
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="propertyvalue2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="firstConfigDataFromDBFactory"
        class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="firstConfigDataFromDB" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DB Properties Initialization -->

    <bean id="firstConfigurationPlaceHolder"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="firstConfigDataFromDBFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="secondConfigurationFromDB"
        class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">

        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="tablename2" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="propertyname2" />
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="propertyvalue2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="secondConfigurationFromDBFactory"
        class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="secondConfigurationFromDB" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 
    Error Map Initialization 
    Subtype of org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
    -->

    <bean id="secondConfigurationPlaceHolder"
        class="com.application.SecondConfigurationPlaceHolder">
        <property name="order" value="3" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="secondConfigurationFromDBFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Generic.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
>
    <!-- Enable annotation scanning -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Initialise connection to Database -->
    <import resource="Spring-Datasource.xml"/>
    <!-- Initialize mail connection -->
    <import resource="Spring-Mail.xml"/>
    <!-- Inject database connection to DAO -->
    <import resource="Spring-DAO.xml"/>

    <!-- Other Beans Below -->

</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
>
    <import resource="generic.xml" />

    <bean id="applicationBean" class="com.application.ApplicationBean" scope="singleton" >
        <property .. />
        <property .. />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am loading `applicationContext.xml` with following statement in code:

```
`appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");`
```

- applicationContext.xml `imports` generic.xml.
- generic.xml `imports` Spring-DataSource.xml.

Comment: And what is `${appenv.deployment}`? How is this set? Also make sure both are in the same application context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated question to clarify your query.

Comment: Is `development.properties` in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: @M.Deinum No, it is in `src/resources`. Its maven based, even `applicationContext.xml` and `log4j.xml` are in same location.

Comment: If it is maven based it must be in `src/main/resources` and not `src/resources`. THe first is the maven default (next to `src/main/java`). Add your directory structure and also expand on how you are loading the `applicationContext.xml` file.

Comment: @M.Deinum In my case it is `src/resources`, I also checked if the properties file is getting copied to `target/classes`. It gets copied there. I am loading `applicationContext.xml` using ` ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. When I hardcode DB parameters in `applicationContext.xml`, it works properly...

Comment: If the placeholders aren't replaced I strongly doubt that both the placeholder and datasource config are loaded in the same configuration. (Hence my request for showing how you load things).

Comment: @M.Deinum Added configuration files. Please have a look.

Comment: You don't happen to have multiple `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` do you?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I do( I have three ), You can see. Its there in `Spring-Datasource.xml`. One loads from property file, other two load from database tables. I have specified `order` too. I have set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to false.

Answer (score 0):

have you added this to your application context file

`<context:property-placeholder location="Path for .properties file"/>`

add this line before the beans

Comment: I think what I have done is another way of doing what you are suggesting. See bean definition for `dbPropertyReader`.